# Canvas on part of screen

Tags: android, canvas

I am creating an app where I want a part of the screen to be drawable. I use the following code to create a canvas but this takes up the entire screen. So I would greatly appreciate you could answer me how to make a canvas appear on only part of the screen and if possible be centered.

```
package com.testing;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

public class testing extends Activity {
TouchView tv;
float x,y;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    tv = new TouchView(this);
    setContentView(tv);
}

class TouchView extends View implements OnTouchListener {
    Paint paint;

    public TouchView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setOnTouchListener(this);
        paint = new Paint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {
        super.onDraw(c);
        c.drawPaint(paint);
        c.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        c.drawText("I LIKE TO DRAW", x, y, paint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        x = event.getX();
        y = event.getY();
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should you Layouts and put CanvasView inside of LinearLayout or something.
Then put that layout inside of Activity.
I'm totally new android but I think this is a way to do it :)